# How to get an open generic type from a string

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a Type[] array and I want to get the Func type where T1, T2 etc... correspond to the types in the array.  The array is not fixed in size but assume a type is available in the runtime (16 in .NET 4, 4 in .NET 3.5).

In .NET 4, I can do this and it works:

```
Type GetFuncType(Type typeRet, Type[] types)
{
    return Type.GetType(string.Format("System.Func`{0}", types.Length + 1))
                  .MakeGenericType(types.Concat(new Type[] { typeRet } ).ToArray())
}
```

In .NET 3.5 however, the Type.GetType for the open generic type fails, returning NULL.

Is there a way I make this work in .NET 3.5?  My only thought atm is to build up a string for the close generic type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way of doing this is to use `Expression.GetFuncType(Type[])` and `Expression.GetActionType(Type[])`. In the case of func, the last `Type` is the return, so:

```
Array.Resize(ref types, (types == null ? 0 : types.Length) + 1);
types[types.Length - 1] = typeRet;
return Expression.GetFuncType(types);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted Marc's answer to this because it's obviously the correct way to do it in this case. However in the mean time I worked out another solution which might be handy in other cases.

The problem with my original approach was related to the Func`{0} type name not being qualified with an assembly reference.  So the alternate fix I found was this (typos not withstanding):

```
typeof(Func<>).Assembly.GetType(string.Format("Func`{0}", types.Length+1));
```

The `typeof(Func<>).Assembly` is a hack to get a reference to the assembly that implements the Func types.